# Angular - Typescript- Trying to push multiple objects into a new array of objects but getting undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am creating an Angular service to fetch data from a specified resource in the backend. this resource will return rows of data as streams and I want to store them in an array so that when I call a service with this method I can gain access to the data of each payload.
I have a method like  such to map stream of data which uses a helper function `extractRecords` shown in 2nd snippet below.

```
getRecords() {
    return this._records = this._resourceService.search(SOMECONSTANT, {})
        .pipe(map(extractRecords))
        .pipe(shareReplay()) as Observable<Data[]>;
```

I have debugged and the issue is that the records[] array below is undefined after I push each array of objects by doing `r.payload.push`

```
function extractRecords(result) {
    const records = [];

    if (!isNullOrUndefined(result)) {
        result.forEach(r => {
            if (!isNullOrUndefined(r['payload'])) {
                records.push(r.payload);
            }
        });
    }
    return records;
}
```

`r.payload` returns an object each time it loops through the code and returns and object like such:

```
  name: "Meredith",
  lastname: "Palmer",
  something: "Micheal",
  identifier: "Scott",
  somethingelse: "Rabies",
  blah: "Awareness",
  blue: "ProAm",
  kneecap: "FunRun"
```

The loop will return 1000's of such objects and I want to store them in the records array as an array of objects so that my record object looks something like:

```
  records: [0]
  name: "Meredith",
  lastname: "Palmer",
  something: "Micheal",
  identifier: "Scott",
  somethingelse: "Rabies",
  blah: "Awareness",
  blue: "ProAm",
  kneecap: "FunRun"
[1]

  name: "Meredith",
  lastname: "Palmer",
  something: "Micheal",
  identifier: "Scott",
  somethingelse: "Rabies",
  blah: "Awareness",
  blue: "ProAm",
  kneecap: "FunRun"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two if's condition inside extractRecords() function. Use the debugger to check if the code is entering each one of them, in other words, put a breakpoint below each if and see if it stops in both.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply!
I have put debuggers there and it stops in both places. in the debugger I observed that records is being populated but when I call ```this.service.getRecords()``` from a component this is undefined?